# How can we detect changes of AppComponent in routing component?

Tags: angular6, router-outlet

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      currencyCode: string = 'INR';

      changeCurrency(currencyCode:string){
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode; }
    }


export class CurrencyExchangeComponent{
       fromCurrency:string = 'INR';
       toCurrency:string = 'INR';

     exchangeCurrency(){
       //service call
     }
}
```

> Whenever i am going to make change on currencyCode which is there in
>   AppComponent it should reflect in CurrencyExchangeComponent also.